# Напечатайте правую и левую цифры, используя для их определения арифметические операторы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано целое двузначное число.

Пример ввода

> 79

Пример вывода

> 9 7

Не пойму, тут нужно работать со строками? Прост тема Числа

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку (кнопка `править`) -- с ней будет проще вам помочь :)

Comment: Нужно посмотреть, какие  есть  "арифметические операторы" для целых чисел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, от вас ожидают чего-то наподобие этого:

```
both = int(input('Введите двухзначное число'))

left = both // 10

right = both - (left*10)

print('%s %s' % (right, left))
```

Не знаю только, можно ли считать целочисленное деление "арифметическим оператором". Но, в случае чего, его можно заменить на `int(both/10)`

Comment: В задании не сказано, что число должно быть двузначным.

Comment: Спасибо и на этом )

Comment: Это я не указал, там ток двузначное.

Comment: А попробуйте лучше вместо `right = both - (left*10)` использовать остаток от деления: `right = both % 10`

Comment: @gil9red, я просто не был уверен, можно ли нахождение остатка от деления отнести к арифметическим операторам. Без этого ограничения, проще было бы вообще написать left, right = divmod(both, 10)

Comment: @Александр, кст да :) И про divmod в точку )

Answer (score 1):

```
tens, units = number // 10, number % 10    # The same as divmod(number, 10)
print(units, tens)
```